# How to show loader until file uploads? Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to add loader icon when I'm uploading some file. How can I set it to last until the upload is done?

I have a simple upload form where I want to upload document and click Save button, then loader should pop up and show itself only until the file is uploaded.

```
<input type="file" (change)="AddFiles($event)" />
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

TS:

```
addFiles(event: EventTarget) {
    // this.file = [];
    const eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
    const target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
    const files: FileList = target.files;
    if (files.length !== 0) {
      this.file = [];
      this.file.push(files[0]);
      this.uploadFlag = true;
    } else {
      this.uploadFlag = false;
    }

  }
```

Thats the code for adding files and what I would like to do is on click of Save show loader until its done.

Comment: What have you tried? How is your code organized and where/how would you want to implement this? Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Comment: @JoshuaOhana explained better

Comment: Where's the onclick method for the Save button? Assuming you're making an http call somewhere just set your flag when it starts and un-set when you get a response back. As for the UI bits, tons of angular loaders out there to use, Angular material has a nice looking one<md-spinner>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<div align="center" *ngIf="result?.length == 0">Waiting ...</div>
  <div id="loader-home" align="center" *ngIf="result?.length == 0">
    <div class="bounce1"></div>
    <div class="bounce2"></div>
    <div class="bounce3"></div>
  </div>
```

Each of bounce class represent one bubble (adjusted with css to bounce one after one)

```
    /* LOADER */
  #loader-home {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%; }
  #loader-home > div {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both; }
  #loader-home .bounce1 {
    animation-delay: -0.32s; }
  #loader-home .bounce2 {
    animation-delay: -0.16s; }
  #loader-home .bounce3 {
    animation-delay: -0.08s; }
```

The "result" variable is the result of your observable

```
 this.data.import(uploadResult)
        .map((res: any) => res.errorMessage)
        .subscribe(result => {
        this.result = result;
...}
```